# Enable the dates from the selected date on weekly, monthy basis

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Currently i am implementing the DatePicker where i am selecting the initial date and then passing that date to another date picker which will give me the only dates that are weekly(day after 7 days) or monthly(Day after 30 days) based on the selected date.
But it seems I am not getting it I Messing it some where.

Adding a sample code for the reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime(2020, 1, 14);

  // DatePicker will call this function on every day and expect
  // a bool output. If it's true, it will draw that day as "enabled"
  // and that day will be selectable and vice versa.
  bool _predicate(DateTime day) {
    print(day);

    if ((day.isAfter(selectedDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1))) &&
        day.isBefore(selectedDate.add(Duration(days: 7))))) {
      return true;
    }


    return false;
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        selectableDayPredicate: _predicate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2019),
        lastDate: DateTime(2021),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
                primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                disabledColor: Colors.brown,
                textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                accentColor: Colors.yellow),
            child: child!,
          );
        });
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0]),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
              child: Text('Select date'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Current Result :

[image]

Can any one guide any better resource for this one or suggest if any one has worked on this one.

Comment: can you tell us what's the current result?

Comment: I have added the result that i am getting.Check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void _datePicker() {
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(2019),
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
).then((value) {
  if (value == null) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {
    _selectedDate = value;
  });
});
```

}

And Where ever you want to use this

```
              Container(
            height: 70,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onPressed: _datePicker,
                  child: Text(
                    'Choose Date',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

this should solve your issue
SO you just need to add initial and last date.

Comment: SO basically you just need to add initial and last date.

Comment: It seems you have not understood the question, I am having issue in enabling the specific dates.

Comment: if you don,t what to keep it hard coded and keep it dynamically as 7 days from date picked or month from day picked you can simply use Provider and according to that you can change the initial and last date.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you want is to only enable dates in interval of weekly or monthly(?)
For example, your current initialDate is 14/01/2020, so it should only enable

- weekly: 21/01/2020, 28/01/2020 and so on.
- Monthly: 13/02/2020 (because 31 days for January).

```dart
  bool _predicate(DateTime day) {
    print(day);

    if (selectedDate.difference(day).inDays == 7 ||
     selectedDate.difference(day).inDays == 30) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Please recheck if any errors cause I did not run this directly.

Comment: I got your point, But for my code is not working in the manner that you have described. Can you add complete working code sample over here which i can refer.

Comment: I'm not back home currently so I can't give an exact working example, can you describe to me what the result looks like after using the sample predicate function I have given?

Comment: Its giving giving error, Failed assertion: line 181 pos 5: 'selectableDayPredicate == null || selectableDayPredicate(initialDate)':

Comment: I made a modification to fix the logic `&&` to `||` but I don't think that error is caused by my code

Comment: Yes its not because of your code.I am checking that one